# Filling holes in a daily time series using Pandas DataFrame misses hole at 00:00

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series stored in a CSV and I dump it into a DataFrame and it looks like this

```
                         time station_id station_name value
0   2019-05-08 00:10:00+00:00    9018823     XXXXXXXX    11
1   2019-05-08 00:20:00+00:00    9018823     XXXXXXXX    10
2   2019-05-08 00:30:00+00:00    9018823     XXXXXXXX     9
3   2019-05-08 00:40:00+00:00    9018823     XXXXXXXX     9
4   2019-05-08 00:50:00+00:00    9018823     XXXXXXXX     9
```

I am using Pandasto fill the holes missing during the day, I only want to do it day by day from `2019-05-08 00:00:00+00:00`to `2019-05-08 23:50:00+00:00`. I've used the following to fill the holes but I am not able to fill the missing one at `00:00`.

```
data = data.set_index(keys=['time']).resample('10min', fill_method='ffill')
```

Is this something I can do with Pandas?

**UPDATE**

Trying as suggested with `reindex` I get the full time span but the resulting  DataFrame has NaN on the values.

```
date_str = data['time'].iloc[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
time_range = pd.date_range(date_str, date_str + ' 23:59:00', freq='10T')

data = (data.set_index(keys=['time'])
            .resample('10min').ffill()
            .reindex(time_range).bfill())
```

```
                     station_id  station_name  value
2019-05-08 00:00:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 00:10:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 00:20:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 00:30:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 00:40:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 00:50:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 01:00:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 01:10:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 01:20:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 01:30:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 01:40:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
2019-05-08 01:50:00         NaN           NaN    NaN
```

Comment: A quick hack is maybe to insert a line at index 0 with a timestamp of 2019-05-08 00:00:00+00:00 and a value of 0. If the sample you pasted above is the head of your dataset then that probably explains why you're missing the 2019-05-08 00:00:00+00:00 point

Comment: What if in other cases the first sample is filled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try `reindex`:

```
# day of data
date_str = data['time'].iloc[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
time_range = pd.date_range(date_str, date_str + ' 23:59:00', freq='10T')

data = (data.set_index(keys=['time'])
            .resample('10min', fill_method='ffill')
            .reindex(time_range).bfill())
```

Comment: Hmm it 'worked'-ish. It added the initial row to the DataFrame but all the columns are nan and none of the values that previously I had with the code I provided

Comment: @jdmg718 seems to work fine with my sample data. Can you try to change `.resample('10min', fill_method='ffill')` to `.resample('10mins').ffill()`?

Answer (score 0):

The function 
`interpolate` has a few different filling methods and directions, try playing with that maybe?

```
date_range = pd.date_range(firstDate, lastDate, freq='10Min')

df = df.reindex( date_range, fill_value=np.NaN)
df = df.interpolate(method='pad', limit_direction='forward', axis=1)
```